# Form action relative URL

Tags: html, forms, post

I have html file like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>

</html>
 <FORM action="/wsd/html_form_check" method="post">
    <P>
    //INPUTS AND LABES AND THINGS
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Send">
    </P>
 </FORM>
```

Now I get an error saying

```
AssertionError: Invalid form action.
```

I suppose it has something to do with the

```
<FORM action="/wsd/html_form_check" method="post">
```

I was told that the HTTP request should look like this:

```
POST /wsd/html_form_check HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
```

So what am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: is that the full path to the file where your doing the check? as im assuming your missing a `.php` or something from the path you want to direct the form too?

Comment: What tool is throwing the error message?

Comment: The error comes from a grader system that our school uses. And thats the full path I was given for this assignment

Comment: Sounds like the grader system is broken.

Comment: Ok got it working eventually. Had to use "http://127.0.0.1/wsd/html_form_check". Thank you everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I had to deal with the same issue.

Consider the following piece of HTML code:

```
<form id="file_uploader" action="/Home/Upload" class="dropzone">
 <div class="fallback">
  <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
 </div>
</form>
```

In the development environment it runs fine. However, deploying it to IIS anywhere else but the root website will cause the action URL to become invalid. For instance, if it were deployed to https://example.com/deployed_app, then the actual action URL that the form will call is https://example.com/Home/Upload, which is invalid.

The solution is to change the action URL to this:

```
<form id="file_uploader" action="~/Home/Upload" class="dropzone">
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to send the data entered in the form to "html_form_check" you haven't used the file extension such as .php or .js. Try adding the file extension and see if that helps !

Comment: If the problem was that the URL was wrong (and there is no requirement that URLs have anything in them that looks like a file extension), the expected error would be `404 Not Found`.